# App is running on all tablets but not running on phone devices

Tags: android, android-activity, android-studio

I am running my application and that is working all fine  on tablets of any type (7 inch or  10 inch). But when ever I tried running it on normal phone device it crashes with lots of error. that is given below:

> **java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.myapp.MainMenu}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #37: Error inflating class** 
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2693)
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2758)
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448)
>                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
>                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
>                                                                                    **Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #37: Error inflating class** 
>                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:640)
>                                                                                       at **com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)**
>                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:689)
>                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:748)
>                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
>                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:821)
>                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:821)
>                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
>                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
>                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366)
>                                                                                       at **com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:435)**
>                                                                                       **at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2267)**
>                                                                                       **at com.mycompany.myapp.MainMenu.onCreate(MainMenu.java:32)**
>                                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6289)
>                                                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2758) 
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177) 
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448) 
>                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942) 
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                                                       at **com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400) 
>                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195) 
>                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException**
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
>                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:614)
>                                                                                       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55) 
>                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:689) 
>                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:748) 
>                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813) 
>                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:821) 
>                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:821) 
>                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511) 
>                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415) 
>                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366) 
>                                                                                       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:435) 
>                                                                                       at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2267) 
>                                                                                       at com.mycompany.myapp.MainMenu.onCreate(MainMenu.java:32) 
>                                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6289) 
>                                                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119) 
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646) 
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2758) 
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177) 
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448) 
>                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942) 
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400) 
>                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195) 
>                                                                                    Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.mycompany.myapp:drawable/main_menu_animboard_hor" (7f0201f0)  is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f0201f0 a=-1 r=0x7f0201f0}
>                                                                                       at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:3708)
>                                                                                       at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3620)
>                                                                                       at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:762)
>                                                                                       at android.widget.ImageView.(ImageView.java:151)
>                                                                                       at android.widget.ImageView.(ImageView.java:140)
>                                                                                       at android.widget.ImageView.(ImageView.java:136)
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
>                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:614) 
>                                                                                       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55) 
>                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:689) 
>                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:748) 
>                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813) 
>                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:821) 
>                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:821) 
>                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511) 
>                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415) 
>                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366) 
>                                                                                       at **com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:435)** 
>                                                                                       at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2267) 
>                                                                                       at com.mycompany.myapp.MainMenu.onCreate(MainMenu.java:32) 
>                                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6289) 
>                                                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119) 
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646) 
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2758) 
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177) 
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448) 
>                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942) 
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400) 
>                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)

I have highlighted some of the lines that I personally think are the reason of this error.

I am getting the two main error that is class not found , where as there is a class also there is a class named tag in the manifest so no problem with this. 
and resources not found , and there are resources I have checked it also. the image lies in the drawable folder.

**I do not know why this error is only occurring on the normal phone device but not on Tablets. Please help me tell me what is wrong?**

Comment: have you made all .xml files required for tablet and mobile @Allay Khalil

Comment: you have that layout file in layout folder??

Comment: @amit vaghela  Under the new android guide lines separate layout file for separate device is depreacted

Comment: of course @dhawal sodha parmar